# Applying chrome extension using Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I have a Chrome extension "EasyView Reader View" installed in chrome. I am trying to open a web page and hoping this Chrome extension will be applied to the page invoked. However, it is not the case. What needs to be done for chrome extension to get applied ?

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import * as path from 'path';
(async () => {
    const pathToExtension = path.join("./Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Extensions/icnekagcncdgpdnpoecofjinkplbnocm/0.8.3_0", '.') // make sure this is correct
    const browserContext = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`
    ]
  });
  const page = await browserContext.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://instagram.com/legal/privacy/", { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 150000 });
  await browserContext.close();
})();
```

Comment: Did you download the .Crv extension separately to use for the browser? Cause you're using path to extension which is already installed in a chrome profile, you could just use the browser you've installed it to using executablePath to open up the browser you've installed the extension in instead if that's what you're looking for.